# Check function using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

I am brand new user of Pytest and unit test logic.

I would like to use `Pytest` module in order to check if function returns same result once it is called. I need to read `Pandas dataframe` and call `corr` function and assert that the value is the same.

```
import pytest
from geb import corr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

re_df = pd.read_csv("../data/prcs1.csv", parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=["Date"])
re = re_df.values

neg_re_df = re_df[re_df < 0].fillna(0)
neg_re = neg_re_df.values

@pytest.fixture()
def test_corr():
    assert pytest.approx(corr(re)) == 0.286
```

Once I run it I stumble upon this error `- FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

How I can read `Pandas dataframe` and test `corr` function against test value?

Comment: It can't find your file, check this location and name are correct: `"../data/prcs1.csv"`

Comment: File is there once I am running in Python interpreter I can read it.

Comment: If you're executing from different locations, your relative path (`"../"`) will be breaking. Change it to provide the full path and try again